# Using the cscope in VIM

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

I'm using cscope -d to look into the source code of the project, I
could use ctrl + ] and ctrl + T, But when I use "ctrl + \" and then
's' , its hanging for little time and not finding the symbol i'm
searching for

Comment: What happens when you use the Ex commands instead of the mappings?

Comment: what are Ex commands ? - I am using his for the first time. Was using source insight previously. Now i'm finding difficult with cscope

Comment: @user2987828 : wat is that

Comment: Control W followed by Control I. If you type `:help ` then control V control W control V control I you will have its help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the corresponding mappings for cscope enabled? Check if you've got something like

```
nmap <C-\>s :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
```

in your vimrc.

If not, you can try copying the mappings you need from http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim into your vimrc.